# Meaning of the sentence in quotation marks

Tags: meaning-in-context

[This BBC article](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-europe-35452306) says:

> A prominent member of the centre-left Social Democrats, Thomas Oppermann, said: "The last German politician under whom refugees were shot at was Erich Honecker" - the leader of Communist East Germany.

The sentence in the quotation marks seems difficult to understand for me. Let me break the sentence into two sentences to comprehend meaning and structure of the sentence.

1.The last German politician was Erich Honecker.

2.Refugees were shot at under Erich Honecker.

So, if the separation of the sentence above is correct, is the politician responsible for arranging armed forces towards refugees?

Comment: The last German politician (of a certain category) ... was Erich Honecker.  "Under whom refugees were shot at" is a prepositional phrase that modifies (qualifies) "last German politician".

Comment: It means that **The last German politician shot refugees (most probably from an air-compressor cannon) at Erich Honecker.**

Comment: Just to be clear, @theonlygusti is either greatly mistaken, or is making a joke. There is no grammatical support for that bizarre reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The separation above isn't correct. The last mandate during which refugees were shot at was the mandate of Erich Honecker, he isn't the last German politician.
2. Refugees were shot at during his mandate. Without more informations it's impossible to determine if he was responsible for the refugees getting shot at, if measures in places before him taking his place as a leader were responsible, was it panic ? Who gave the order ?

If you do a little research:
It's stated that it was in communist east Germany so this was before 1991. Honecker was in office from may 1971 till october 1989. He was proud of the Berlin Wall and loads of people were killed trying to cross it. Are these the refugees Merkel talked about ?

Answer (score 2):

The refugees who were fired upon for attempting to enter Germany were those trying to cross the border to Bundesrepublik Deutschland from Deutsche Demokratische Republik, in English, to the Federal Republic of Germany (West Germany) from the German Democratic Republic (East Germany).  The East Germans authorized the killing of those trying to escape their country starting with the formation of their country in 1949 until the Berlin Wall came down in 1989.

Wikipedia cites a history of the Berlin Wall in quoting Erich Honecker:

> Firearms are to be ruthlessly used in the event of attempts to break
>   through the border, and the comrades who have successfully used their
>   firearms are to be commended.

Honecker was an East German politician, widely reviled in both Germanies.  He held the position of General Secretary of the Socialist Unity Party starting in 1971 and the position of Chairman of the State Council starting in 1974, holding both posts until shortly before the Berlin Wall came down.  These positions made him the head of government and head of state for East Germany.

The sentence you quote equates Germans shooting refugees fleeing from the Middle East with the East German policy of shooting Germans fleeing the East German dictatorship.  And it does so by invoking the name of Honecker, the last German politician to preside over that policy.